# -webkit-animation-play-state not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

I've set up a simple JSFiddle to illustrate the problem:

[where's the paused state?](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rv9y/)

Can anyone tell me why Safari shows the animated element in a paused state as expected, but in Chrome the animation is running?  I'm using Chrome 33.0.1750.146, and wonder if this is a bug with the latest build.  Or am I completely missing something....

Here's the CSS of the paused element.

```
#blue-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-animation-name: blueBox;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2000ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: blueBox;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-duration: 2000ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: It does work in 'Version 35.0.1884.0 canary' but does not work in 'Version 33.0.1750.149' (latest). So I guess this is just a bug in the latest build.

Comment: @alpipego Thanks for that confirmation.

Comment: Did you happen to find a fix/work around for this problem? I'm getting exactly the same thing.

Comment: I haven't.  I was assuming that this would be an obvious bug that would be patched and released quickly, but apparently not.

Comment: @MattDietsche `paused` state working ok at chromium 33.0.1750.152

Comment: Same for Chrome in 2022. 7 years later!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152 Ubuntu 13.10.  Animation starts immediately even though animation-play-state is paused.  On hover the animation stops. Once you move away from animation it and back on over it begins working.

Works fine on Firefox 28.0.

Comment: Same for me. Still, for Chrome in 2022!