# -webkit-animation-play state ignored in chrome but works in safari?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation, webkit

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PB4BB/165/) - Here is a link of an animation thats similar to what I am using in my site. I've found that in safari the animation delays for the specified time the runs as it should. However in chrome the animation is firing straight away as if the animation play state is being ignored.

The version of Chrome I am viewing it in is 33.0.1750.152

After a lot of research I managed to find this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361643/webkit-animation-play-state-not-working-in-chrome) (so I know I'm not going mad) but it was never really resolved and I was hoping someone might know a work around or if there is something wrong with the css I'm using?

The thing thats strange is there are other css3 animations in my site that are working as they should.

```
.one{
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: one 45s infinite cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.01s;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    z-index: 4;
}

@-webkit-keyframes one {
0% { opacity: 0; 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
1%{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); 
}
2%{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
    opacity: 1; 
}
15%{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1; 
}
20% { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0; 
}

25% { opacity: 0; }
30% { opacity: 0; }
35% { opacity: 0; }
40% { opacity: 0; }
45% { opacity: 0; }
50% { opacity: 0; }
55% { opacity: 0; }
60% { opacity: 0; }
65% { opacity: 0; }
70% { opacity: 0; }
75% { opacity: 0; }
80% { opacity: 0; }
85% { opacity: 0; }
90% { opacity: 0; }
95% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting included javascript / jquery pieces at original post may perhaps be helpful.

The javascript (`jquery`) pieces at linked jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/PB4BB/165/) from original post try to access `"animation-play-state"` property on `jquery` `.css()` `object`, that is

At http://jsfiddle.net/PB4BB/165/ linked at original post:

> `$(".one, .two, .three, .four").css({"animation-play-state": "running"
>   ..})

Though `"animation-play-state"` not a jquery object accessible through `.css()`, at least that aware of, or have had success accessing at that approach, utilizing that specific `property` notation.

`WebkitAnimationPlayState` maybe not a `jquery` object, also, that aware of at jquery source. The `DOM` `element` `style` perhaps where the `WebkitAnimationPlayState` `property` exist. If utilize `jquery` `$(selector)` to access `DOM` `element` to set `animationPlayState`, perhaps try `$(selector).get()` or `$(selector)[0]`.

Try this

```
$(".one").get(0).style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/UJ728/

Thanks for sharing.

Hope this helps