# webkit-animation-play-state doesn`t work on chrome

Tags: html, css

Yesterday I wrote on stack question about spinning circles. I get solution answer but I want to rewrite code for working on :hover. And this is main problem. Its doesnt work on chrome but it works perfect under mozilla.(by doesnt work i mean it is rotating all time. And i need it to rotate on hover)

**Code:**

HTML

```
<div class="loading">
    <div class="circle-small"></div>
    <div class="circle-medium"></div>
    <div class="circle-big"></div>
</div>
```

CSS http://jsfiddle.net/EPy52/3/

Comment: define "doesnt work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `animation-play-state` after you called the `animation` itself, else the rule seems to be override .

Calling it later in the sheet sees the rule working.

http://jsfiddle.net/EPy52/5/

Comment: Tried this. Not worked for me. Chrome Version 97.0.4692.71. In 2022.

Comment: @Garavani Version 97.0.4692.71 (Build officiel) (64 bits) works for me and so Version 97.0.4692.99 (Build officiel) (64 bits) . What's not showing is the image that the op do not longer share online ;)

Comment: Thanks for your interest, Cyrillus! I am not sure if I understand what you mean by ‘op’. However, while working fine on Safari and Firefox for my code I had to add the “paused” state on document ready with jQuery to make it work with Chrome. (placement behind animation in the CSS didn’t do the job). Maybe, however, this is related only to my code. Your fiddle seems to work fine.

Comment: @Garavani thks for the feedback.  it sounds clearer to me now , I was surprised and confused that it did not work nowdays, for op see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424366/does-op-mean-original-poster-or-original-post ;) And , yes the answer is about to redefine later the animation-play-state value

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in Chrome: [-webkit-animation-play-state not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361643/webkit-animation-play-state-not-working-in-chrome)

If possible, you should pause it throught Javascript, as in http://www.browsersupport.net/test-cases/CSS/CSS_Test%3A_-webkit-animation-play-state%3Apaused

Answer (score 0):

I got it work, I think it is a specificity issue in your css. Try using:

```
div.circle-medium, div.circle-small {
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state:paused;
}
```